# Logstash Separate patterns

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

We have created separate patterns for each of the logs of the Application Server. All the patterns are good. But we wanted to include a static JSON value to say that this JSON object is from a pattern. Is there any way we can achieve this using the log stash pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`add_field` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-common-options) in your `grok` filter to add another arbitrary field.

```
filter {
  if [type] == "type1" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "pattern1" }
      add_field => { "static" => "static value 1" }
    }
  } else {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "pattern2" }
      add_field => { "static" => "static value 2" }
    }
  }
}
```